# Unity Game Object is not seen in Event System Raycast

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new at unity and I'm trying to do very simple thing. As you can see there are only two object in my scene under Canvas object. This is the script I added both Ground and Deneme objects.

```
Code (CSharp):
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
 
public class Ground : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
   
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
       Debug.Log("Ground clicked");
    }
 
 
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
               
    }
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
   
       
    }
}
```

I wanted to see ground clicked when I click on the ground object. But it doesn't seen. Console stays empty when I click on ground. But when I click on "Deneme" Image object, console says "Ground clicked."

I wondered why it works on deneme object and doesnt works on the ground. So I looked at EventSystem. Raycasty doesnt simply detect ground object. It has a boxcollider 2d.

So why can it be happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the [IPointerClickHandler docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html), you'll see

> Use the IPointerClickHandler Interface to handle click input using OnPointerClick callbacks. Ensure an Event System exists in the Scene to allow click detection. ***For click detection on non-UI GameObjects, ensure a PhysicsRaycaster is attached to the Camera.***

Since you mention BoxCollider2D, I'm assuming the Square gameobject, is not a UI element, but a 3D plane/Quad or sth, with a BoxCollider2D. This is not a UI element. For that you need to attach a Physics Raycaster onto the MainCamera, well in your case, a Physics2D Raycaster.

Also another thing to note, is the Collider's shape. If you go to the BoxCollider2D component in the inspector, you'll see a button called Edit Collider. If you click on it, you'll probably see a green dot in the middle of the gameobject in SceneView. That means that your collider does not take your actual object's size into account. e.g. Width:1 and Height 1 when your object has Width 100 and Height 100. While in editing mode, play around with the values for Width,Height in the Inspector, until you see the green dot becoming a Rectangle. You'll also see 4 green handles which will allow you to resize the rect freely. You can also set the Width and Height to the same values as the equivalents of your RectTransform. Not sure if there's a better way to keep them synced, as I've never had to use sth like this.